# What is the best way of pulling json data in terms of performance?

Tags: wcf, json, webrequest

Currently I am using `HttpWebRequest` to pull `json` data from an external site, and the performance was not good. Is `wcf` much better?

I need expert advice on this..

Comment: Do you control the server? I'm guessing not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not, but that's not the right question.

To answer it: WCF, which certainly supports JSON, is ultimately going to use `HttpWebRequest` at the bottom level, and it will certainly have the same network latency. Even more importantly, it will use the same server to get the JSON. WCF has a lot of advantages in building, maintaining, and configuring web services and clients, but it's not magically faster. It's possible that your method of deserializing JSON is really slow compared to what WCF would use by default, but I doubt it.

And that brings up the really important point: **find out why the performance is bad**. Changing frameworks is only an intelligible optimization option if you know what's slow, and, by extension, how doing something different would make it less slow. Is it the server? Is it deserialization? Is it network? Is it authentication or some other request overhead detail? And so on.

So the real answer is: profile! Once you know what the performance issue really is, you can make an informed decision about whether a framework like WCF would help.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: no.

The longer answer is that WCF is an API which doesn't specify a communication method, but supports multiple methods.  However, those methods are normally over SOAP which is going to involve more overheard than a JSON, and [it would seem the world has decided to move on from SOAP](http://blog.feedly.com/2009/03/03/jsonrest-vs-xmlsoap/).

What sort of performance are you looking for and what are you getting?  It may be that you are simply facing physical limitations of network locations, in which case you might look towards making your interface feel more responsive, even if the data is sluggish.

It'd be worth it to see if most of the latency is just in reaching the remote site (e.g. response times are comparable to ping times).  Or, perhaps, the problem is the time it takes for the remote site to generate and serve the page.  If so, some intermediate caching might be best.

Answer (score 0):

+1 on what Isaac said, but one thing I'd add is, if you do use WCF here, it'll internally use the HttpWebRequest in most places, so you're definitely not gaining performance at all. One way you may unintentionally gain in performance -- however -- is in how WCF recycles, reuses, pools, and caches most transport objects internally. So it ultimately goes back to Isaac's advice on profiling.